# Force ARM build instead of x86 in VS cordova for windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to publish my app to windows store.
Desktop windows app is already in store, and now i want Windows Phone too.
The problem is that when i build it and selecting the ARM option(which is also the only option), VS builds x86 instead.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
------ Build configuration options: --release
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c     "<my_project_dir>\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat --release --archs=x86 --phone --buildConfig=<my_project_dir>\build.json""
```

Note the **x86** there.

Comment: It was just solved after latest Cordova tools for visual studio update.